# Disable syntax highlighting for CDATA in Atom.io

Tags: syntax, colors, highlighting, cdata

I use Atom editor and I have a template files with nested HTML in CDATA tag, so all HTML code is like 1 color.

Is possible to "ignore" CDATA? I want HTML syntax highlighting in that CDATA (see example). I cannot remove that CDATA because of template engine.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>
    <header>
    </header>

    <entity id="main"><![CDATA[
         <div>LOT OF HTML CODE HERE</div>  
    ]]></entity>

</template>
```